# Convert SVG Data to SVG File that can be uploaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, fabricjs

Using canvas.toSVG as listed here: [Creating a backing canvas with FabricJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234722/creating-a-backing-canvas-with-fabricjs/34238050?noredirect=1#comment56224699_34238050) I am able to convert my HTML5 Canvas to SVG Data that looks like this by calling canvas.toSVG():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="85.999967in" height="55.812440in" style="background-color: #ffffff" viewBox="0 0 650 421.84" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.0-rc.1</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g transform="translate(516.24 217.93) scale(0.47 0.47)">
<image xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAyADIAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB…lq4JVWvJFVClTiCkAAgF9IIBHyAQACB/oAf6+gMzMMVWDEN7kh5AkN0dEwR3++iCe/+ez9f//Z" x="-200" y="-193.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="400" height="387" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

However, I need to be able to upload a .svg file via AJX or Node (i.e Request, or Unirest) to a vendors API.

How do I convert the SVG/XML Data above to a SVG File that can be saved then uploaded?

This is what I was using for .png, but when I used a multiplier, large canvas upscaling would crash the browser, so that is why I am attempting toSVG. The png is automatically base64 encoded, so it is decoded in Node, streamed to a temp directory, then posted as follows:

Client Side:

```
 // Multiply Canvas
        var img = canvas.toDataURL({
            // Multiplier appears to accept decimals
            format: 'png',
            multiplier: 5        
});

 $http.post('/postVendor', { filename: filename, file: img }).success(function (data) {...
```

Server-Side/Node:

```
app.post('/postVendor', function (req, res, next) {

    var filename = req.body.filename;
    var file = req.body.file;
    var fileloc = 'upload/' + filename;

    //var base64Data;
    fileBuffer = decodeBase64Image(file);

    fs.writeFileSync('upload/' + filename, fileBuffer.data);

 unirest.post('http://myvendorsAPI/ws/fileuploads')
.headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' })
.field('filename', filename)// Form field
.attach('file', fileloc)// Attachment
.end(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
        //fs.unlinkSync(fileloc);
        res.send(response.body);
    });
})
```

Since toSVG outputs XML, how would I make this into a SVG file, and how would it be uploaded?

Comment: That XML *is* an SVG file.  SVG is an XML based file format.

Comment: But you will win nothing by getting your canvas to this svg: it's just a JPEG version of your canvas wrapped into an svg image element. If you want to rescale it, you ll have no more benefits than the png version.

Comment: I was able to push it as just the XML. Naming the file with an extension of .svg worked from what I could tell. It seemed to scale well, but I see that the data tag is jpeg. Should that/can that be changed?

Comment: I what you do draw onto your fabricjs canvas is a pixels image, no there is no way.

Comment: @Kaiido fabricjs draw things starting from an object representation that allows the library to draw a vector from it. of course it cannot upscale low quality picture, but it does for so many things.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, I didn't gone into fabricjs sources as you did, but are you telling that it is able to vectorize pixel external resources ? If not, that's just what I was saying to OP, he can't avoid the embedding of the data version of his pixellatted images drawn into the canvas. If yes, I'll start to dig into fabricjs' sources right now ! (drawing operations on the canvas are vector based, so this is obviously easier to replicate those in an svg markup)

Comment: pixels stays pixels. but imagine to have a 5mpx picture, draw it on a 200x300 canvas. if you export it with dataUrl you will have a 200x300 picture. if you export  with toSVG you have a 5mpx drawn on a surface as big as you want. whatever else you draw ( text, gradients, vector decoration, frames) will stay vector. also hand drawing is shape based.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi But still the 5mpx image will be embedded as a dataURI encode image into the svg, So yes, if the appended original image is bigger than the canvas, he will be able to scale it with the svg version, but when you look at his svg markup, there is **only** this image, so why to pass through fabricjs + toSVG ?

Comment: Main reason ( i got from previous question ) is to scale bigger than canvas can handle. he wants to export up to 24000x16000 for what i understood. of course in this particular case explained here there is no advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var file = canvas.toSVG({
  // Multiplier appears to accept decimals
  width: '200mm',
  height: '300mm'      
});

$http.post('/postVendor', {
  filename: 'myfile.svg', file: file 
}).success(function (data) {...}
```

on the server side, there is no need to decode the base64 encoding because you are just uploading text and URL encoding from ajax should be enough.

Comment: That did it. It looks great!